# Conditional EventHandler

Tags: java, events, jpanel, actionevent

Can I make anonymous event handler method to act conditional like

```
JButton activeDataBtn = new JButton("Active");
activeDataBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try { 
        if (activeDataPanel.setVisible(false)) { //Erroneous code 
            readDataFromFile();  //a method reads data from .csv
                               //file and shows it on activeDataPanel
            activeDataPanel.setVisible(true);
         }
     else 
         activeDataPanel.setVisible(false);   
     }
  }
 });
```

how can i make this conditional?

Comment: Any suggestions appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, but that code is not valid:

```
if (activeDataPanel.setVisible(false))
```

maybe you want to check if your panel is visible try it this way:

```
if (activeDataPanel.isVisible())
```

or maybe `activeDataPanel.getVisible()` I'm not sure about the getter name for it right now :)